# download Android SDK components without the Android SDK manager

Tags: android

is posible download Android SDK components without the Android SDK manager?
in windows xp

Comment: what do you mean by sdk manager?

Answer (score 8):

Yes, it's possible. Have a look at the contents of https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/repository.xml

And then you can fetch, for example, https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/android-2.1_r01-windows.zip directly.

Answer (score 0):

The SDK Manager use under the hood the files https://dl.google.com/android/repository/repository2-2.xml and https://dl.google.com/android/repository/repository2-3.xml Here you find all the links to the components you see in the Android Studio SDK Manager.

Like `Android SDK Platform 34` from https://dl.google.com/android/repository/platform-34-ext7_r02.zip