# Where can I download android sdk manually?

Tags: android

I met some problem (I have to use socks proxy but only http proxy is used by the sdk manager) when downloading the sdk through "Android sdk manager". So i am wondering if it is possible to download the sdk manually from somewhere and then put them back in the sdk directory.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html

Comment: @phil:it download the sdk manager only.

Comment: Possible [duplicated](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2459873/1050058) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2766713/1050058)

Comment: I meet same problem. Android SDK manager doesn't support socks proxy, but JVM support proxy. Edit $(SDK)/tools/android, go to last line. put '-DsocksProxyHost=... -DsocksProxyPort= ... ' in exec command, JVM will download stuffs from the socks proxy. it works for me

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This website provides links for individual APIs and other tools that should help you:

http://www.hariadi.org/android/manual-download-of-android-sdk-components/