# Download and install platform-28_r06 manually for android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm trying to run virtual device with in android studio. It needs to install `platform-28_r06.zip`, but download process doesn't complete due low internet speed.

I want to download this file  manually but I don't know where I should extract the content.
SDK path is `C:\Users\lion\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk`.
[image]

Comment: Probably a duplicate unless the process has changed again. https://stackoverflow.com/q/13188545/1531971

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Explore your SDK path.

You'll see a *platforms* folder. Here are *android-** platforms.

For API-28, the path is then: *SDK/platforms/android-28/*

The platform tools are in *SDK/platform-tools/*.

Answer (score 0):

you can download through cmd locate the sdkmanager.bat in android studio folder sdkmanager.bat --sdk_root=${ANDROID_HOME} "platform-tools" "platforms;android-28"